# How to process Web API response in C# Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, request, httpclient

In server part I have authentication end point in ASP.NET web API where I send http request which contains email and password, and get http response with access token or exception code + message like "Incorrect password or email". In client part (WPF) I have service with method which send this authentication request to server and (at this moment) it returns only response model for success (token), but how I can return exception model if user write wrong password?. Inside method I know I can check http response status and based on this return token or exception model. Use "out" for token and return for exception?

**Server**

```cs
public AuthentificateResponse Authentificate(AuthentificateRequest model, string ipAddress)
{
    //Check if account exists, is verified and password is correct
    Account account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == model.Email);
    if (account == null || account.VerifiedDate == null || _hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(account.PasswordHash, model.Password) == Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        throw new RequestExeption("Email or password is incorrect");
    // Generate short-live access token and refresh token
    string jwtToken = _jwtUtils.GenerateJwtToken(account);
    RefreshToken refreshToken = _jwtUtils.GenerateRefreshToken(ipAddress);
    //Add refresh token to account and remove all expired tokens
    account.RefreshTokens.Add(refreshToken);

    removeExpiredTokens(account);
    _context.Accounts.Update(account);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    AuthentificateResponse response = _mapper.Map<AuthentificateResponse>(account);
    response.JwtToken = jwtToken;
    response.RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token;
    return response;
}
```

**Client**

```cs
public async Task<AuthentificateResponse> Authentificate(AuthentificateRequest model)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(_baseUri, "Accounts/authentificate"));
    string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    request.Content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    AuthentificateResponse authentificateResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthentificateResponse>(responseJson);
    //Only for success result
    return authentificateResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could modify your api as below:

```
 public IActionResult SomeAction(SomeDTo dto)
        {
            var result = new AuthenticateResult() { JwtToken = "Somejwttoken", RefreshToken = "SomeRefreshToken" };
            if (somelogical)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return Unauthorized("");
        }
```

And make a judgement in your clientside with the statuecode of response